# nested forms in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm trying to setup a nested form and the main thing I can't get working is knowing when to do the build method. Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

In all the examples I've found, which appear to be pre-rails 3, I see the following two methods:

```
user.address.empty?
user.address.build
```

I have managed to winnow out with my semi-asleep Google-Fu that the build has been replaced with:

```
user.build_address
```

What I'm trying to figure out is what's the replacement for empty? It doesn't appear to exist when I try things at the console, but user.build_address is wonderful.

Any ideas?

thanks...

Comment: er, maybe I'm overthinking this. user.address.nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the has_one relation build_address will create an empty address instance or will load already existing instance. So you don't need to call `user.address.empty?`.